# Create three identical websites that use different resources?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am starting a new web project that contains three identical sites. The only thing that differs is that each site has its own resources (database with ASP.NET membership, XML, and `web.config)`.

I  would like to know if it is possible to setup a website project that uses different resources for different sub folders.  Additionally, how do I setup virtual folders in a project solution?

The websites would look like this: [www.mysite.com/es/](http://www.mysite.com/es/), [www.mysite.com/uk/](http://www.mysite.com/uk/) and [www.mysite.com/au/](http://www.mysite.com/au/).

I don't want to create different projects for each site because I want to be able to use the same classes and controls for all of the sites.

My biggest issue is how to setup virtual folders and make each folder access its own membership database.

Any tips on how I can set this up?

Comment: Deleted my answer. Good luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds likes this is more of a deployment issue than a development issue.

On your live web server, create the three folders in the root of the web site.  Make each of them be their own Application (using IIS Manager).  You should be able to google for the instructions for your particular version of IIS.

Install a copy of your project to each of the folders. Make the appropriate changes for to each web.config files for each database, ...

Now you will have three separate web applications running off of the same code base.